# How to listen to redis queue

Tags: redis, resque

What is better way to start resque worker

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='*'
```

OR

```
rake resque:work QUEUE='queue1,queue2,queue3'
```

Does using * make resque slower?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, explicitly stating `QUEUE=*` will not make Resque any slower, as monitoring all queues is Resque's default behavior, unless overwritten by the `QUEUE` environment variable, when run via a rake task.

However, your statement of "which is better between:"

```
QUEUE="queue1,queue2,queue3" rake resque:work
```

and

```
QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

*could* be two different things.  If you have more than just the three queues of `queue1`, `queue2`, and `queue3`, then Resque could perform undesired work.  However, ultimately, the queues Resque listens to has no effect on the startup of the worker, which is largely affected by the size of your app, dependencies, etc.